# ggplot Duration object

Tags: r, ggplot2, time

I try to plot with ggplotly this kind of DF :

| TIME | DURATION |
| --- | --- |
| 02/06/2021 17:36:56 | 02:52:52 |
| 02/06/2021 22:07:57 | 11:19:06 |
| 03/06/2021 10:34:55 | 07:07:08 |
| 03/06/2021 18:22:53 | 02:16:28 |
| 03/06/2021 21:23:20 | 04:37:25 |
| 04/06/2021 08:48:51 | 03:10:13 |
| 04/06/2021 12:53:36 | 00:09:52 |

I change my column duration in "period format", with the library lubridate.
Here is my code

```
DF[,1] <- as.POSIXct(strptime(DF[,1],"%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"), tz="GMT")

DF[,"Duration"] <- hms(DF[,"Duration"])

A=ggplot(DF, aes(Time, Duration)) + geom_point()
```

R return :

> Warning message: Removed 112 rows containing missing values (geom_point).

It seems that it doesn't understand this kind of format... Nevertheless function plot works : `plot(DF$Time, DF$Duration)` so I don't understand why ggplot doesn't work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

df <- tribble(
  ~TIME, ~DURATION,
  "02/06/2021 17:36:56", "02:52:52",
  "02/06/2021 22:07:57", "11:19:06",
  "03/06/2021 10:34:55", "70:07:08"
)
df
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   TIME                DURATION
#>   <chr>               <chr>   
#> 1 02/06/2021 17:36:56 02:52:52
#> 2 02/06/2021 22:07:57 11:19:06
#> 3 03/06/2021 10:34:55 70:07:08

df <-
  df %>%
  mutate(
    TIME = TIME %>% parse_date_time("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"),
    DURATION = DURATION %>% hms()
  )
df
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   TIME                DURATION  
#>   <dttm>              <Period>  
#> 1 2021-06-02 17:36:56 2H 52M 52S
#> 2 2021-06-02 22:07:57 11H 19M 6S
#> 3 2021-06-03 10:34:55 70H 7M 8S

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(TIME, DURATION)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_time() +
  scale_y_time()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: This sounds good but the problem is that I have a lot of lines in my DF (over 300). I just put an extract here. 
How do I perform the "tribble" function on all my lines?
Thank you very much for your help.
Julie

Comment: Tribble is only to get the example data running. You already have the object `DF`, but I have to create (at least part of) it. You can just start with `DF %>% mutate`

Comment: Oh right I understand.
I have now an other problem. Here is the error:

'Warning: Problem with `mutate()` column `Duration`.
i `Duration = Duration %>% parse_time("%H:%M:%S") %>% as.duration().
i 7 parsing failures.
row col           expected   actual
 26  -- time like %H:%M:%S 50:57:05
 32  -- time like %H:%M:%S 36:44:36
 34  -- time like %H:%M:%S 24:37:15
 38  -- time like %H:%M:%S 68:29:40
 46  -- time like %H:%M:%S 48:58:42'

I think it waits for less than 24 hours, whereas I sometimes have 60 hours duration.... How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @lunae_majicam I revised my answer.